Нужно ли обособить запятыми оборот "впервые за долгое время"?
В 2022 году впервые за долгое время в Кизнере прошел велопарад.

При таком порядке слов – да, нужно обособить:
В 2022 году, впервые за долгое время, в Кизнере прошел велопарад.
Графически и интонационно значимость оборота "впервые за долгое время" вырастет с такой записью:
В 2022 году – впервые за долгое время – в Кизнере прошел велопарад.

Спасибо большое!

@Наталья И вам за вопрос!
